# ¿Como puedo llenar un dropdown con datos de la base de datos?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, vistas, dropdownlist

Estoy intentando llenar un dropdown con datos de la base de datos

Modelo

```
[Key]//set as Primary key
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] //autoincrementable
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Tipo { get; set; }
    public String Descripcion { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListaDePermisos { get; set; }
```

Controlador

```
   ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: TiposDeUsuarios
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var tdp = new TiposDePermisos
            {
                ListaDePermisos = PruebaHG.ListaDePermisos.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.Tipo.ToString()               
                })
            };
            return View("Index", tdp);
        }
```

Vista

```
    @model IEnumerable<PruebaHG.Models.TiposDePermisos>
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Tipo, new SelectList(Model.ListaDePermisos, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
```

Errores:
Model.Tipo  IEnumerable no contiene una definición para Tipo, ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión...
Model.ListaDePermisos    El mismo error
PruebaHG.ListaDePermisos   El tipo o nombre del espacio de nombres 'ListaDePermisos' no existe en el espacio de nombres'PruebaHg'

Comment: No esta claro lo que preguntas, intenta redactar la pregunta de otra manera..

Comment: Consigues traer al controlador los datos?

Comment: No te quedes con el "quiero", la idea es que lo hagas y en base a eso, podamos orientarte... Lo que publicas son sólo ideas sueltas, que cabe mencionar no están muy lejos de lo que deseas hacer colega.. anímate! :)

Answer (score 0):

Para rellenar un dropDown desde la bd primero has de obtenerlo hacia el controlador con una clase parecida a esta:

```
public List<TipoDePermisos> GetPermisos()
        {
            //Tu cadena de conexión 
            using (var connection = BD.GetOpenDB())
            {
                var sql = @"Query";
                var rows = connection.Query(sql);

                var clases = rows.Select(r => new ArticulosPropiedades
                {
                    PropiedadID = r.Field<int>("Id"),
                    PropiedadNombre = r.Field<string>("Nombre"),

                });

                return clases.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Ya definida la manera en que obtenemos los datos de la lista en el controlador escribimos:

```
public ActionResult Vista()
        {
            IEnumerable<TipoDePermisos> listaPermisos = _referenciaClaseConexion.GetPermisos();
            return Json( new
            {
                data = listaPermisos
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Por ultimo en la vista debemos obtener con el viewModel la lista de datos

```
public class ListaDatos
{
    //has de incluir esto en tu VM
    public List<TiposDePermisos> Permisos { get; set; }
}
```

y realizar el dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Permisos , new SelectList(Model.Permisos , "PropiedadId", "PropiedadNombre"), new { @class = "input form-control input-lg", @required = "required", @style = "height: 40px; font-size:16px" })
```

Comment: gracias... ¿Cómo puedo cambiar query para que quede con EF? @Nicolas

Comment: No entiendo bien tú pregunta, creo que lo que quieres decir es que dónde pone query, pongas tu consulta sql