# Pasar valores de un DropDownListFor al controlador mediante Url.Action

Tags: mvc, web, asp.net-core

Estoy atscadisimo en un punto: Basicamente quiero pasar los valores seleccionados de un DropDownListFor a una acción del controlador. El problema lo tengo en como introducir los valores del dropdown en la lista que paso a la accion a traves del url action. Pongo el código:

Esta es mi vista View:

```
   @{List<string> etiquetas = ViewBag.etiquetas; }
     <b><br>Etiquetas<br></b>
     <td class="input_check"><b><label>Etq 1</label></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Np, new SelectList(etiquetas))</td>
     <td class="input_check"><b><label>Etq 2</label></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Np, new SelectList(etiquetas))</td>
     <td class="input_check"><b><label>Etq 3</label></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Np, new SelectList(etiquetas))</td>
     <td class="input_check"><b><label>Etq 4</label></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Np, new SelectList(etiquetas))</td>
     <td class="input_check"><b><label>Etq 5</label></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Np, new SelectList(etiquetas))</td>
     <td class="input_check"><b><label>Etq 6</label></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Np, new SelectList(etiquetas))</td>
     <td class="input_check"><b><label>Etq 7</label></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Np, new SelectList(etiquetas))</td>
     <td class="input_check"><b><label>Etq 8</label></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Np, new SelectList(etiquetas))</td>
     <td class="input_check"><b><label>Etq 9</label></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Np, new SelectList(etiquetas))</td>
   @{ List<string> etiquetasSimulador = new List<string>();}
```

Aquí el botón que me retorna al controlador:

```
<input class="estilo2" value="Validar Salario" type="button" id="shift_validar"
 onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("simulador", "Simulator", new { etiquetasSimulador = "3", variablesSimulador = "2" })'" />
```

Y, finalmente, la acción del Controlador, con el pase de parametros que responde correctamente según he debugueado:

```
public IActionResult simulador(List<string> etiquetasSimulador, List<string> variablesSimulador)
{
            return View();
}
```

Basicamente, el problema lo tengo en como rellenar esta lista

```
   @{ List<string> etiquetasSimulador = new List<string>();}
```

con los valores de los dropdown. El sistema no me reconoce el siguiente tag Helper:

```
@HtmlDocument.getElementById("loquesea")
```

Ya que no me deja importar y usar

```
@using System.Windows.Forms
```

debido a que me encuentro en Net.core y es una aplicación de MVC, no de forms.

Llevo toda la mañana con esta tontería... alguna solución, por favor??

Un saludo, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Buscas algo [asi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/251614/como-puedo-llenar-un-dropdown-con-datos-de-la-base-de-datos/251625#251625) ?

Comment: Hola @NicolasOñate ! Muchas gracias por las respuestas. He mirado tu solución y creo que se referían a como rellenar un dropdown. Yo lo que quiero es rellenar una lista con los valores seleccionados en los dropdown. Como he comentado, no me deja hacer uso del @HtmlDocument.getElementById()

Comment: quieres que despues de que `simulador` se ejecute te muestre los datos?

Comment: Nop, basicamente quiero rellenar la lista. Pero no hay manera, estoy super atascado

Comment: has probado a pasarle los datos desde el controlador?  `return View("NombreVista", new NombreModeloVM{ DatosAPasar= DatosAPasar });`

Comment: Igual me he explicado mal... Si el pase de datos lo hago sin problemas, tanto de controlador a vista como vicerversa. El problema lo tengo intentando rellenar esta lista 

      @{ List<string> etiquetasSimulador = new List<string>();}

con los valores que hayan sido seleccionados en los dropdown, mas que nada porque no me es posible coger elementos mediante id.

Comment: No se si tienes que hacerlo completamente desde las herramientas de asp, pero creo que podrías lograrlo con javascript muy facilmente

Comment: Si, con javascript tengo claro como se haría, por eso no tengo problema. La cosa es hacerlo con asp integramente. Muchas gracias Nicolas!

Comment: Puedes agregar tu html generado?

Comment: con asp.net directo no puedes a menos que a la propiedad etiquetas le agregues un padre para identificar digamos Grupo1.Etiquetas, Grupo2.Etiquetas y no es recomendable solo generas mas variables con los mismos datos, asi que deberas usar javascript

Comment: Muchas gracias Miguel

Comment: Hola de nuevo. Por alguna extraña razon ahora me dice que no existe la funcion js. La cosa es que el propio snippet me reconoce el nombre de la funcion. He instanciado el fichero con la funcion en el fichero _Layout y he llamado a la funcion en el onclick, y lo unico que me dice es que no la encuentra, por no decir que directamente no me reconoce la carpeta de js.

Answer (score 0):

Por alguna extraña razon ahora me dice que no existe la funcion js. La cosa es que el propio snippet me reconoce el nombre de la funcion. He instanciado el fichero con la funcion en el fichero _Layout y he llamado a la funcion en el onclick, y lo unico que me dice es que no la encuentra, por no decir que directamente no me reconoce la carpeta de js. Dejo aquí como he instanciado a la funcion. En el fichero startupa.cs he comprobado que esta activada la configuracion para carga de ficheros estaticos.

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/js/script_1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/simulador.js"></script>
</environment>
```

y esta es mi llamada a la funcion:

```
 <input class="estilo2" value="Calcular Salario" type="button" 
  onclick="simuladorSalarial()"/>
```

Aluna idea @MiguelZarate o @NicolasOñate ?? Muchas gracias!